# cfcomponent web service - getting SOAP attributes

Tags: web-services, soap, coldfusion

Here is a SOAP request example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ws="http://ws_test">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:testService a1="a1" a2="a2">
         <ws:e1>e1</ws:e1>
         <ws:e2>e2</ws:e2>
      </ws:testService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And here is my example cfc web service:

```
<cfcomponent style="document" wsversion = 1>
    <cffunction name="testService" returntype="String" access="remote" >
        <cfargument type="string" name="e1"/>
        <cfargument type="string" name="e2"/>

        <!--- Missing: code to extract a1 and a2 --->   

        <cfreturn "#e1# #e2#">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

I'm new to Coldfusion and web service, and I have no idea on how to extract attributes **a1** and **a2** from **`<testService>`**, googled it but can't find any reference. Any ideas?

=== Edit ===

Thought it might be useful if I attach the type definition:

```
<complexType name="testServiceType">
    <sequence>
        <element name="e1" type="string"></element>
        <element name="e2" type="string"></element>
    </sequence>
    <attribute name="a1" type="string"/>
    <attribute name="a2" type="string"/>
</complexType>
```

Note that although this is my test web service, but it is based on a data schema that is provided by our partner, which means my web service has to conform with it.

=== Resolution ===

Based on Gerry's answer, this is what I ended up doing:

```
<cfcomponent style="document" wsversion = 1>
    <cffunction name="testService" returntype="String" access="remote" >
        <cfargument type="string" name="e1"/>
        <cfargument type="string" name="e2"/>

        <cfset soapReq = getSOAPRequest()>
        <cfset soapXML = xmlParse(soapReq)>
        <cfset attributes = soapXML.Envelope.body.XmlChildren[1].XmlAttributes>

        <cfset a1 = attributes.a1>
        <cfset a2 = attributes.a2>

        <cfreturn "#e1# #e2# #a1# #a2#">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I think you need getSoapRequest() and then parse it using the code from the answer given by keshav-jha

```
<cfcomponent style="document" wsversion = 1>

    <cffunction name="testService" returntype="String" access="remote" >
        <cfargument type="string" name="e1"/>
        <cfargument type="string" name="e2"/>
        <cfscript>
            soapReq=GetSOAPRequest();
            soapXML=xmlParse(soapReq);
            bodyAttributes = {
                a1:soapXML.Envelope.body.XmlChildren[1].XmlAttributes.a1
                ,a2:soapXML.Envelope.body.XmlChildren[1].XmlAttributes.a2
            };
            return serializejson(bodyAttributes);
        </cfscript>

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerry, didnt know about the GetSOAPRequest() function. Not what I was expecting (ie. a built-in function that does it), but it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to parse your XML and then get the value of a1 and a2

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myXML" >
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws_test">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:testService a1="a1" a2="a2">
         <ws:e1>e1</ws:e1>
         <ws:e2>e2</ws:e2>
      </ws:testService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</cfsavecontent>
 <cfset parXML = xmlParse(myXML) />
<cfdump var="#parXML.Envelope.body.XmlChildren[1].XmlAttributes.a1#">
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I think you are talking about something that is unrelated to cfcomponent web service, as in your example you have the XML document to work with, but I don't think that is the case when working with cfcomponent web services, or I could be wrong, and please correct me if that is the case.

Comment: I was wrong, with Gerry's latest post I now see what you were trying to say (like I said, I'm new to Coldfusion and web service). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the web service, then you have complete control over how the webservice is consumed.  In this case a1 and a2 are not ever passed into the CFC for processing.  So if they have meaning, you can set them up as parameters like e1 and e2.

One of the best tools I've ever used for understanding and using web services is [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).  If you create the example.cfc and point SOAPUI at it, you will get an XML request that looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.stack">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:testService>
         <soap:e1>e1</soap:e1>
         <soap:e2>e2</soap:e2>
      </soap:testService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If you want to process a1 and a2, there is no reason not to handle them as regular arguments.

So you could make a CFC that looks like this:

```
<cfcomponent style="document" wsversion = 1>

    <cffunction name="testService" returntype="String" access="remote" >
        <cfargument type="string" name="a1"/>
        <cfargument type="string" name="a2"/>
        <cfargument type="string" name="e1"/>
        <cfargument type="string" name="e2"/>


        <cfset var ret=serializeJSON(arguments) />
        <cfreturn "#ret#">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And if you point SOAPUI at it, then it will generate a SOAP envelope that looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://soap.stack">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:testService>
         <soap:a1>?</soap:a1>
         <soap:a2>?</soap:a2>
         <soap:e1>?</soap:e1>
         <soap:e2>?</soap:e2>
      </soap:testService>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: SOAP UI is great, I have been using it.The data schema is defined by our partner and my part is to create the web service, therefore it can not be changed to be elements like you have suggested.